# Glide not loading image from url

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a problem I'm loading image from url with Glide but I need to make a validation if a logo url is null, then take another url  to get the image from, but it isn't working and I don't know why

```
     @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(SearchHorizontalAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            holder.mTitle.setText(premiumsList.get(position).getName());

            if(premiumsList.get(position).getLogo_url_string()==null){
           Glide.with(this.activity).load(premiumsList.get(position).getUrl()).into(holder.mImg);
                Log.d("",String.valueOf(premiumsList.get(position).getUrl()));
            }
else{
            Glide.with(this.activity).load(premiumsList.get(position).getLogo_url_string()).into(holder.mImg);
    }
        }
```

Comment: what is this.activity ? If you are in activity you can simply try ActiivityName.this or if you are in fragment just try getActivity()

Comment: Could you provide any form of logcat output if possible

Comment: It makes no difference :/

Comment: I edited my question with the log output but it only shows the value of getUrl(); that's why It is rare that glide does not load the image from there :/

Answer (score 2):

You have take care about little things :

1. Pass correct context based on Activity/Fragment
2. Use .placeholder
3. Use .error for easily identify issue

Comment: I am passing the corrrect context because the ones from Logo_string_url does show them,it only does not show the ones from getUrl, I'm sorry but how do I use the others? I'm sorry if the question is dumb but I just started using Glide  and also android :/

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Please try this and provide the stack trace if possible

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SearchHorizontalAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.mTitle.setText(premiumsList.get(position).getName());

    if(premiumsList.get(position).getUrl()!=null){

        Glide.with(this.activity).load(premiumsList.get(position).getUrl())
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                Log.e("IMAGE_EXCEPTION", "Exception " + e.toString());
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                Log.d("Sometimes the image is not loaded and this text is not displayed");
                return false;
            }
        })
        .into(holder.mImg);
    }
    else{      
        Glide.with(this.activity).load(premiumsList.get(position).getLogo_url_string()).into(holder.mImg);
    }
}
```

Comment: that causes my application to crash, that adapter I pass it to a fragment in a recylcler :/ and it only does not load the ones from getUrl the ones from getLogo_url_string() does load them :/

Comment: could you also Log the getLogo_url_string @HeberSolis

Comment: you're right let me try that haha, but I'm certain that it is the same as getUrl() because it is also in cloudinary

Comment: I have internet permissions it only does not load the ones from getUrl the ones from getLogo_url_string it does load them

Comment: @HeberSolis also your logic is slighly flawed your if and else conditions need to be switched. Let me edit my answer to preview those changes. In the meantime I'll check further into the other issue

Comment: ok thank you very much!, I still haven't resolved the issue :(

Comment: Don't worry there will be a way to fix it. Try running the code I've now provided and see if any errors are popping up in logcat :)

Comment: I copy and pasted as it is to avoid mistakes and it marks an error in the .into(holder.mImg); part cannot resolve that method// sorry a ) was missing :P

Comment: It does not work :/ , nothing appears in the logcat :/

Comment: @HeberSolis as a last resort I added another Log statement in the onResourceReady(). see if this log statement is appearing: "Log.d("Sometimes the image is not loaded and this text is not displayed");"

Comment: @HeberSolis did you manage to solve this issue I didn't hear back. It would be useful to know how you solved it if so. :)

Comment: Hi! no, sadly I didn't :/